Texture display problem in Blender 4.2
I recently updated my Blender to the recently released version 4.2 passing all my configurations and Addo-ns from 4.1 without problems...expecting that now with certain models this error occurs when I want to view their materials, the same with Evee, this error does not occur It happened to me in 4.1 because they open normally and are displayed well but I don't know what's happening, help please.


Model Archive:  

There are millions of reasons this could be happening. I think this is a time to share your blend file. https://blend-exchange.com

Here it is:  More... While editing the file to make it smaller I discovered a "fix"...basically the file and the other one have a node called "DAZ Volume" inside the file, when I deleted that node everything went back to normal for some reason and it's gone the effect...why did that happen? What was that node? Because in version 4.1 it is present in the file and did not cause problems..  @TheLabCat

You’re supposed to edit that HTML into your question, but this works.

Try to switch CUDA/OptiX render device to None to see if it works.
